# Komma vor »und umgekehrt«?

Tags: comma, parenthesis

Was ist die korrekte Kommasetzung?

1. > Wenn A gilt, dann gilt B und umgekehrt.
2. > Wenn A gilt, dann gilt B**,** und umgekehrt.

Ist 1 oder 2 korrekt?

Answer (score 5):

Was bedeutet denn "und umgekehrt" in diesem Satz? Es kehrt die Wenn-dann-Konstruktion um:

> (Wenn A gilt, dann gilt B,) und (umgekehrt). =
>   (Wenn A gilt, dann gilt B,) und (wenn B gilt, dann gilt A).

Ohne Komma macht die Konstruktion keinen Sinn:

> Wenn A gilt, dann gilt (B und umgekehrt).

Was soll denn "B und umgekehrt" sein?

Answer (score 0):

Möchte man den Gegensatz betonen (indem man eine kurze Pause vor dem "und" einlegt), würde ich das Komma als korrekt betrachten, ansonsten eher ohne.